# Callback called before loading dependency

Tags: requirejs

I want to apologize for this stupid question; I'm new to RequireJS. This is my code:

```
require(['jquery', '/javascripts/underscore.js'],
    function($, _) { console.log($().jquery, _); }
);
```

For some reason, `console.log(_)` prints `null`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'/javascripts/underscore.js'` needs to be changed to `underscore'. Gosh, this is badly explained in the docs.

Answer (score 3):

First off, make sure the paths to your dependencies are correct. Is jQuery in a different path than underscore? Make sure your paths are relative to the HTML page loading require.js.

You can also set the baseUrl using `require.config()`.

Secondly, drop the .js from the end of `javascripts/underscore`. This is explained in the API docs, but it's a little buried. (http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-baseUrl).